# Common rules or house rules to resolve catching dispute

Tags: ghost-catch

In Ghost Catch (Geistes Blitz original name) the idea is that you grab the correct item before any other player can. Obviously the one player having the correct item in hand wins the round. However incidentally we end up with the situation that 2 players each hold one end of the correct item. Or players grab for the correct item but none of them manages to actually get it and it falls off the table. Or even worse, one player grabs for the wrong item but accidentally tips over the correct item and another player therefore doesn't manage to grab the correct item. We have come up with the house rule that then no one wins the round, the card is being shuffled back into the deck, and so the same round will come up again later in the game.

I feel this is not always fair, and if this happens near the end of the game and the deck is very small players can predict what the next card might be and gain an unfair advantage.

I'd like to know whether there is an actual rule or perhaps an errata or a successful (house) rule to solve these kind of situations.

[image]